# Struggling to get Kodi running on Ubuntu Server 14.04.2

Tags: drivers, server, xorg, opengl, kodi

I've just finished building a new machine and installed Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS (typical install from USB flash drive). I'm currently having issues trying to get Kodi up and running (I suspect) thanks to Server's general lack of graphics support..

The machine in question has:

- Asus M5A78L-M/USB3
- AMD Phenom II x6 1100T
- Onboard Radeon HD3000 series (RS780L)

To summarise what I've tried so far, after working through numerous tutorials and guides, I am at a stage where attempting to launch Kodi shows the following output:

```
Error: unable to open display
Kodi needs hardware accelerated OpenGL rendering.
Install an appropriate graphics driver.
```

For the graphics side, I attempted the steps covered [here](https://trick77.com/2014/11/28/how-to-install-kodi-ubuntu-server-14-04/), but although the AMD variation would require `xserver-xorg-video-amd` instead of the Intel package the guide uses, I get the following message:

```
Package xserver-xorg-video-and is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

Running `lspci -nn | grep VGA` shows one entry:

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780L [Radeon 3000] [1002:9616]
```

I did find [this Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) that mentioned a `fglrxinfo` to list basic OpenGL details.. However, after installing `fglrx`, that info command gives me a `Error: unable to open display (null)` message.

Could somebody please help me get this up and running? All my search results looking for answers are now turning up pages I've already visited and didn't find a solution on..

*Edit 1:* Not sure if this is relevant, after installing `fglrx` and restarting, it seems my terminal view resolution has changed, now everything is now stretched horizontally (my monitor runs a 1920x1080 res natively). However, I still get the same message from `fglrxinfo`.

*Edit 2:* I've just downloaded and installed KodiBuntu on the system listed above.. I need this same machine to double as a web development server, VirtualBox host, local cloud server, etc., which was why I went for Ubuntu Server initially. But it seems this will allow me to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fglrxinfo` needs an X display running the `fglrx` driver. Assuming you have that, if you're trying to run `fglrxinfo` over SSH or from a TTY it won't have a `DISPLAY` environment variable set so you'll need to specify it manually, like so:

```
DISPLAY=:0 fglrxinfo
```

Assuming the display is `:0`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still get the same response with `DISPLAY=:0 flgrxinfo` though. All actions I've performed from the start have been through `tty1` on the machine directly, with a standard monitor attached to the onboard graphics port. I do understand Ubuntu Server is designed to be a headless OS with no graphical interface included by default, so with all this talk of displays, does this mean I'm simply missing some software requirement or is it something else?

Comment: You have to have started X, yes. Being that this is Server, you have to do that yourself. This can get a bit hairy but I've written a tutorial for creating a Chrome kiosk. You can (indeed I *have*) applied the same logic and techniques to run a Kodi media centre. http://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/

Comment: that's awesome, thanks for the link. I'm at work at the moment so I can't do anything about it right now, but I will definitely have a proper read through your post when I get home this evening. :)

Comment: So, as you pointed out, the only step I was missing was launching X before Kodi. A few minor adaptations of the scripts in your post on "thepcspy" got Kodi up and running for me without any problems. :) Thanks for the info, I've learnt something new today..